# join 2 variables in jQuery

Tags: jquery

What is the best and more efficient way of joining two variables together in jQuery?

```
    classes_tab.click(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        (home+contacts).fadeOut(500, function(){
            classes.fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
```

Comment: "+" doesn't work I think it's that used for strings?

Comment: Join them together to act on them both, or to concatenate two strings? What's *in* the variables? A node-reference, a string, an array, an object..?

Comment: What exactly are `home+contacts`?

Comment: home and contacts are 2 variables and I need them to fadeOut when I click on "classes_tab", thanks

Comment: @Alex still to vague: What is the exact value of the variables and which result do you expect after the join?

Comment: they are static variables as the just represent classes values used in the HTML, that's all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
classes_tab.click(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        home.add(contacts).fadeOut(500, function(){
            classes.fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
```

Assuming both `home` and `contacts` are jQuery selections, you can merge selections by calling the `.add(selector)` method.

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .add() method constructs a new jQuery object from the union of those
>   elements and the ones passed into the method. The argument to .add()
>   can be pretty much anything that $() accepts, including a jQuery
>   selector expression, references to DOM elements, or an HTML snippet.

Here's a simple fiddle that shows toggling of two objects that have been merged.
http://jsfiddle.net/N3W9F/

Comment: this worked, however I was hoping that you could join variables by simply separating them with a comma as it looks more clean and tidy way of doing it

Comment: @Alex: You can always create a new variable containing both elements and then work with it as in `var newMergedSelection = sel1.add(sel2)`, if it feels cleaner but jQuery is thought to be used with chained method calls

Comment: I guess this is the way I like to work, it feels more clean for me but thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If by joining variables, you mean multiple selectors, this is the syntax :

```
$("div,span,p.myClass")
```

Have a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)